# Consumir un enpoint con mas de 800 mil registros con dataTable en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatable

No se como hacer para desarrollar un endpoint que me devuelva los 800 mil registros, que el servidor no se caiga y que el dataTable pueda consumirlo sin errores, perdon alguien me puede dar una idea?

Comment: Y es estrictamente necesario esa magnitud de datos?

Comment: En verdad es necesario mostrar esa cantidad de datos? Digo, tus usuarios veran 1 x 1 los 800 mil?

Comment: Claro, puedo mosrar menos cantidad de datos en el datatable limitandolo, eso lo entiendo pero como desarrollar un enpoint que me devuelva esos 800 mil datos para que luego el dataTable pueda consumirlos. Esa mi duda de como hacerlo, pense desarrollar un paginador que lleve una cierta cantidad de datos y luego cuando quieras pasar de pagina consuma otro endpoint para mostrar los siguientes. Es lo que estoy un poco complicado

Comment: Opciones desde hacer chunk hasta las lazy collections

Comment: EL problema es que me tira este error Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) y no creo tener que configurar el servidor para entregar esos datos. Quiero hacerlo de la manera menos invasiva posible

Comment: Lamentablemente lazy collections  no la puedo utilizar por que tengo la version 5.8 de laravel

Comment: El endpoint me tiene dar acceso a esos 800000 registros, un aplicacion de un servidor consume a otra que que esta en otro servidor, el datatable no voy a mostrar mas de 20 datos pero si necesito tener acceso a los 800000. Necesito utilizar dataTable y otra cosa no se ocurre hacer.. Voy a ver si con chunk puedo trabajar con el datatable.